# How to change the columns of multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 8 dataframes I am working with. I want to rename all of the columns of each data frame to the same strings. I have tried:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9]
renames_dfs = []
for df in dfs:
    renames_dfs.append(df.rename(columns={'column1':'column2','column3':'column4'}))

#renames_dfs
```

Where I would keep going with the column names beyond 4. It also would put the new renamed dataframes in a list, whereas I want them to be new variables.

Comment: most things in pandas default to working on a copy of the dataframe. If your issue is that you just want to rename inplace, the parameter is probably `inplace=True`, but check the docs to be sure

Comment: If you have multiple (unknown number of) frames that are related you should either concatenate them or put them in a list. Do not dynamically create variables, that is an antipattern in python.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to me. Why do you have 8 DataFrames? Why are you trying to rename the columns instead of concatenating all the DataFrames?

Comment: @user1558604 This makes the new list of dataframes return None 8 times.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted what you are trying to do. Do you not just want to rename the existing dfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this, to rename those columns:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9]
renames_dfs = []
for df in dfs:
    df.rename(columns={'column1':'column2','column3':'column4'}), inplace=True)
```